# How to filter data in ng-grid on the basis of date range

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Using **$scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText** i am able to filter my data. For example to filter on the basis of Destination Country, i am setting the filterText as:

```
$scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText += 'DestinationCountry:' + $scope.filter.DestinationCountry + ';';
```

However i am unable to figure out how to filter a date column on the basis of date range i.e. between from-date and to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I recently researched this same issue. I don't believe it is possible to filter a date column by range using filterOptions.filterText as of ng-grid v2.0.7. The reason is that ng-grid runs a regex filter on the string representation of the data. If you take a look at the [code here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/v2.0.7/build/ng-grid.debug.js#L2497), ng-grid executes the cellFilter for the given column and then searches the resultant string. There would be some cases where you could construct an appropriate regex given that you know the cellFilter date format (e.g. "201[01]" to search for 2010 and 2011), but this wouldn't work for every date filtering case you would have.

That leaves your best option as server-side filtering. Of course you could always open an issue on github and request this functionality in a future version. Also, it might be possible to write a plugin to filter the rows with a custom function, but I haven't dug into this yet.